# Another way of generating a list of special elements in python

Tags: python, list

```
listA = ['000','001','010','011', '100','101','111','110']
```

To get the above list I usually use the following code. My aim is to get all the possible combinations of 3 numbers where each number can either be `0` or `1`.

```
listA = list(range(0,222))
listA = [str(x).zfill(3) for x in listA]

 listA = [x for x in listA if not x[-3] in [str(z) for z in range(2,10,1)]]
 listA = [x for x in listA if not x[-2] in [str(z) for z in range(2,10,1)]]
 listA = [x for x in listA if not x[-1] in [str(z) for z in range(2,10,1)]]
```

This only works if `list(range(0,222))` is relatively small, for large range like `(0,222222222222)`, `listA = list(range(0,222222222222))` returns `Memory error`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You should investigate `itertools.product`.

Comment: This is the Cartesian product of a list (`['0', '1']`) with itself (three times in total), with each result joined up. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a = [''.join(p) for p in product('01', repeat=3)]
>>> a
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just binary strings from `0` to some end number?

You could do:

```
def zn1(up):
    w=len(f'{up:b}')
    return [f'{x:0{w}b}' for x in range(up+1)]
```

Or, if memory is an issue, use a generator:

```
def zn1(up):
    w=len(f'{up:b}')
    for n in range(up+1):
        yield f'{x:0{w}b}'
```

The first for example:

```
>>> zn1(7)
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']

>>> zn1(2000)
['00000000000', '00000000001', '00000000010', '00000000011', '00000000100', 
...
'11111001100', '11111001101', '11111001110', '11111001111', '11111010000']
```